# Align Shortcut info to right in Tkinter Menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I'm writing an application in Tkinter and I'm creating a ctrl+s save feature and I want to show that in the menu, but I can't get the actual text "Ctrl+S" to right align in the command. I tried using tabs as in the following example, but that didn't work, and I couldn't find anything on it. Here's what I tried:

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.label = Label(self.root, text="Welcome to dummy program")
        self.label.pack(padx=40, pady=20)

        self.file_menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)

        # In the next two lines is where I need the text aligned to the right
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save As \t Ctrl+S", command=lambda: self.label.config(text="Saved!"))
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open \t Ctrl+O", command=lambda: self.label.config(text="Opened!"))

        self.root.mainloop()

Gui()
```

But here's what I want it to look like:
[image]

And I'm not sure how to control the spacing and alignment. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Menu items have an `accelerator` attribute specifically for this purpose:

> **accelerator** Specifies a string to display at the right side of the menu entry. Normally describes an accelerator keystroke sequence that
>   may be typed to invoke the same function as the menu entry. This
>   option is not available for separator or tear-off entries.

```
self.file_menu.add_command(..., accelerator="Ctrl+S")
```